# Writing a mock function for testing a login application

Tags: authentication, mocking

I am making the authentication of my android application, I want to send the entered password & email in json format then my web service is going to test if they are correct then it will return the result in json format also.

But before doing this, I want to make a mock function that replace my webservice and do this just to test before .
Here is the code 
After making the validation of interface(Email & password are valid )
mock class
`if(fault==false)
                //new AttemptLogin().execute();
                new GetUser().execute();`
My class GetUser is here (the mock class that will replace my web service )

```
     private class GetUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String e2=email.getText().toString();
        String p2=password.getText().toString();
        if (e2 != null && p2!=null) {
            try {
        JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(e2);
        JSONObject jsonObj2 =new JSONObject(p2);
        UserEmail=jsonObj1.getJSONObject(TAG_Email);
        UserPassword=jsonObj2.getJSONObject(TAG_Password);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String c=checkLogin(UserEmail, UserPassword);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),c,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    return null;
}
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        if (result != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

And this is the method checkLogin that check if the user has logged with the  right email & password .

```
      protected  String checkLogin(JSONObject UserEmail,JSONObject UserPassword) {

            String e ;
            String p;
            String r="";
            try {
                e= UserEmail.getString(TAG_Email);
                p = UserPassword.getString(TAG_Password);


            if (e.equals("exemple.android@yahoo.fr") &&
                p.equals("123456")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello imene!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            r="ok";




            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seems like you 're not imene!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts--;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "number of Remaining login Attemts ="+numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts == 0) {
                    validate.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Locked!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    r="ko";



            }
            }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return r;
        }`
```

But ,i don't have any result .Can any one tell me where is the problem in my code .